# web.py database select access

Tags: python, web.py

I have been messing around with web.py lately and wanted to grab some stuff from a db and its returning me a "Storage" object. an the code i am using to call my info is:

```
db = web.database(dbn='sqlite', db='sqlfile.sqlite')
sely = db.select('carp', order="id ASC")
```

when sely runs it drops me out text like so:

`<Storage {'lvl': 0, 'symbol': u'formb', 'logged': u'false', 'id': 1, 'display': u'Classic'}>`

when you print out sely the storage line comes out. how can i get the dictionary out of this object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general Python trick for dealing with unknown APIs is to use the [`dir` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir). Try `dir(sely)` in the interpreter to see what member variables and functions are defined for the object you get.

- If you see something like [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), you can call `list(sely)` to convert the results to a list, and generally iterate over the object in a loop.
- If you see something like `__getitem__`, then you can index into the object and hope to get a value back.

As a side note, I just tried out your code and I get `sely` to be a `web.utils.IterBetter` instance (which returns 0 rows, instead of expected 3 in my case). So I cannot really reproduce your problem (but have problems of my own, so to speak).

Answer (score 3):

```
db = web.database(dbn='sqlite', db='sqlfile.sqlite')
sely = db.select('carp', order="id ASC").list()
```

`sely` would be a `list` of storages, `storage` is the same as `dict`, but you can access arguments with `obj.key`, instead of `obj["key"]`. You can do `dict(obj)` to convert `storage` into `dict`.

Answer (score -1):

in windows

`return list(db.select('top',what='score',where="name = $id",vars=locals())`

is ok. you can get the score‘s value.

but

in ubuntu

you shuld do it like this

`db.select('top',what='score',where="name = $id",vars=locals())[0]["score"]`

i don't know why but it works in my computer