# Convert web.py iterbetter to dictionary or list

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary, web.py

I'm trying to get the some data from a MySQL table (ipb_members) using web.py's database.select. This is the code I'm using: `members = db.select("ipb_members", where="name=\"asdfquerty\"")`

it returns an instance of iterbetter. What I'm trying to figure out is how to convert that to a dictionary or a list. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560948/web-py-database-select-access), which recommends using list(), but that just puts everything in the first index. I've also tried dict(), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
members = db.select("ipb_members", where="name=\"asdfquerty\"")
for member in members #members is IterBetter
    print member.posts #member is Storage
```

Note that you dont have to call `.list()` on the result of `db.select` if you need to iterate over it only once.

Comment: It still dumps everything (including the `<Storage {` bit) into `members[0]`.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. `Storage` is the same as `dict`, but you can access the values by using dot syntax `record.attribute` instead of `record["attribute"]`.

Comment: But that's just the problem, it doesn't work. When I try to print `members.posts`, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: IterBetter instance has no attribute 'posts'`

Comment: Does your table `ipb_members` has a column called `posts`? Looks like you are expecting it to automagically load rows from other table. web.py provides a convenient wrapper over your database, it is not an ORM.

Comment: Yes, there is a column called posts in ipb_members (it's a post count, not storing actual post content.)

Comment: `db.select` returns `IterBetter` that is like a `list` of queried records that you can iterate only once, every record in this list is a `Storage` object that is just like a `dict`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `dict(members)`?

Comment: It outputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 74; 2 is required

Comment: Selecting from database always returns list, why would you call `dict` on that? You have to iterate over the selected records, and call `dict` on each of them, but I don't understand the purpose of that, using `Storage` objects is more handy.

Answer (score 0):

iterBetter is not very convenient as it can only iterate once, here is code convert iterBetter to list:

```
list_conv_from_db = []
for menber in menbers:
    temp = dict()
    for key in menber:
        temp[key]=menber[key]
    list_conv_from_db.append(temp)
```

then you get list_conv_from_db you can do everything you want!